# Does else if condition run if the the first if condition was true in branch coverage testing?

Tags: if-statement, testing, branch, test-coverage

Given the following scenario:

```
    If (condition1)
        statement..
    Else if (condition2)
        statement..
    Else if (condition3)
        statement..    
    else end
```

My question is --> In line / Branch coverage testing, if the first condition is true, is it possible for the second condition to run?

Note: if --> Else if not if --> if

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four possibilities of execution (I added a statement for the last `else` case):

```
                        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
If (condition1)         | * | * | * | * | 
    statement..         | * |   |   |   |
Else if (condition2)    |   | * | * | * |
    statement..         |   | * |   |   |
Else if (condition3)    |   |   | * | * |
    statement..         |   |   | * |   |
else                    |   |   |   | * |
    statement...        |   |   |   | * |
end if                  | * | * | * | * |
```

The asterisks denote which statements/conditions are executed/evaluated for each of the 4 scenarios.

As soon as one of the indented statements is executed, no other conditions or statements are evaluated in that construct.

In testing that has branch coverage, the tests include several different states, so that the conditions (hopefully) are sometimes false and sometimes true in such a way that each branch gets executed in at least one test. If this is the case then you have *branch coverage*.

But this does not mean that during ***one*** of those tests the above depicted schema is violated. Also in these test runs, if the one `if` condition returns true, the remaining conditions remain unevaluated.

Comment: Thanks you sir.. That makes sense :)